# CSS behaving differently on local machine and on server

Tags: html, css, django, amazon-ec2

It might be a silly question but CSS on my remote EC2 server behaves differently than my local server. I mean when I load the page and inspect it, the css rules being followed are different. I have already ran collectstatic. Following is the code in my main.css

```
div.wrapper-home h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arimo", cursive, sans-serif;
}
```

It loads perfectly on local machine when i run it on remote server it only picks up css for h2 which is something else and not for the class wrapper-home. Can anyone guide me in right direcion for what I might be missing?

Comment: How are you hosting it? If your using rails for example it might not be being over written in the asset pipeline. All CSS gets run on client side so as long as the file gets delivered to the browser the CSS should render the same

Comment: I'm assuming you're running it on the same computer? Are you sure your cache has been cleared since the last update to the server?

Comment: @Godwin I am using same computer. I have cleared my cache on the server.

Comment: @CharlieDavies I am hosting using fabric in django. How can i refresh the client cache to run new CSS?

Comment: Did you load the Arimo webfont in your online document? Apparently it is out of the google Webfont repository

Comment: @MichelFeldheim Yes, I was using Arimo, but changing it didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Using "Inspect" or "Inspect Element" in your browser (decent browsers have these developer tools) you should be able to find the "Computed" style that is differs between the cases -- this should also tell you the source file of that style.

Is the source the file you expect it to be?

Comment: No, the source files are different, though I expect it to be the same. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Is it a the wrong version of the correct file? Or a completely different file?

Answer (score 0):

One day I had a similiar problem using Windows. Windows is case insensitive (filesystem) so on a desktop I had a Style.css and in HTML I included style.css (on windows this worked perfectly). On the server (linux, case sensitive) this does not work.

Please put more details about your case, desktop system, server system, other technologies. Maybe you are using some builders or specific clients or this happened on a specific browser?

Comment: I am using ubuntu for development and my deployment server is also on ubuntu.